# which are the resolutions i need to slice my psd?

Tags: android

Here is my code for android fragment which is having an image.
My problem is when i selecting a fragment having image in some android verions it force closing.
Please help e to fix the issue.

**Java**

```
    import com.imagezoom.ImageAttacher;
    import com.imagezoom.ImageAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener;
    import com.imagezoom.ImageAttacher.OnPhotoTapListener;

    import info.paarva.CrescentBuilders.R;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.RectF;

    public class FragmentTab2 extends Fragment {
         ImageView mImaView;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_tulip_locationmap, container, false);


            mImaView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationmap_tulip);

            Bitmap bimtBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.tulip_locationmap);
            mImaView.setImageBitmap(bimtBitmap);

            /**
             * Use Simple ImageView
             */
          usingSimpleImage(mImaView);
          return rootView;
        }

        public void usingSimpleImage(ImageView imageView) {
            ImageAttacher mAttacher = new ImageAttacher(imageView);
            ImageAttacher.MAX_ZOOM = 2.0f; // Double the current Size
            ImageAttacher.MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f; // Half the current Size
            MatrixChangeListener mMaListener = new MatrixChangeListener();
            mAttacher.setOnMatrixChangeListener(mMaListener);
            PhotoTapListener mPhotoTap = new PhotoTapListener();
            mAttacher.setOnPhotoTapListener(mPhotoTap);
        }

        private class PhotoTapListener implements OnPhotoTapListener {

            @Override
            public void onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y) {
            }
        }

        private class MatrixChangeListener implements OnMatrixChangedListener {

            @Override
            public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {

            }
        }

    }
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".locationmap_tulip"
    android:background="@color/textclr_actnbar"
        >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationmap_tulip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:src="@drawable/tulip_locationmap" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
12-13 06:54:11.792: W/dalvikvm(1417): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4ca7b20)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): Process: info.paarva.CrescentBuilders, PID: 1417
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:452)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:482)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at Tulip.FragmentTab2.onCreateView(FragmentTab2.java:29)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-13 06:54:11.800: E/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 06:59:11.828: I/Process(1417): Sending signal. PID: 1417 SIG: 9
12-13 06:59:12.196: D/dalvikvm(1468): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 93K, 4% free 3765K/3920K, paused 6ms, total 7ms
12-13 06:59:12.212: D/dalvikvm(1468): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3983K/4144K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
12-13 06:59:12.228: I/dalvikvm-heap(1468): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.366MB for 2536932-byte allocation
```

Comment: Try to add this properties : android:largeHeap="true" to <application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Chance of force closes is reduced but in some cases it is force closing again.

Answer (score 1):

It's closing, as you've seen, because it's running out of memory. If you control the resolution of this image, don't make it any larger than the highest res phones now out there (2,560 x 1,440). But to take into account the lower res devices, the vast majority out there, still implement the suggestions in [the Android docs for handling large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Their basic technique is to check bitmap dimensions first, then scale as appropriate to the device screen size so only displayable pixels are held in memory.